# Java binary search tree and hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable, binary-search-tree

for my coursework(binary search tree and hashtables) I would like to make a java program that scans a text file and orders words based on the most frequent words. Something like most popular tags.

Example: 
 1. Scan the file. 
 2. List words that appears more than once

WORD TOTAL 
Banana      10 
Sun         7 
Sea         3

Question 1. is how do I scan a text file?
Question 2. how do I check for duplicates in the text file and number it?
Question 3. how do I print out the words that appears more than 1 time out in the order like my example?

My programming is not strong.

Comment: Okay... but you haven't asked a question. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: which is the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is course work, I'm not gonna provide you full details, but I'll try to point you in a possible direction:

1. Google how to read words from a text file (this is a very common problem, you should be able to find tons of examples)
2. Use for instance hashmap (string to int) to count the words: if a word is not in the hashmap yet, add it with multiplicity 1; if it is in there, increment the count (you might want to do some preprocessing on the words, for instance if you want to ignore capitals)
3. Filter the words with multiplicity more than 1 from your hashmap
4. Sort the filtered list of words based on their count

---

Some very high-level implementation (with many open ends :) )

```
List<String> words = readWordsFromFile();

Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new HashMap<>();
for(String word : words) {
    String processedWord = preprocess(word);
    int count = 1;
    if (wordCounts.containsKey(processedWord)) {
        count = wordCounts.get(processedWord)+1;
    }
    wordCounts.put(processedWord, count);
}

removeSingleOccurences(wordCounts); 
List<String> sortedWords = sortWords(wordCounts);
```

Comment: I managed to read the file and using Map to count. But something is wrong since it only counts the alphabets and not the words.

Comment: @jdnhldn in order to read words, you should do a `readLine` repetitively (until there are no more lines) and split the line by space.

Comment: Wish I could show you my work applied now after that little pseudocode of your. However I was not allowed to answer my own question. Any suggestion on how I can paste the code in here to update the progress?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Multiset from Guava Lib: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset